# Two websites, same design & structure, only some entries are shared

Tags: multi-site-manager, multiple-sites

I need to build a double website.

- Both sites must use different domain names
- Both sites share exact same design & structure
- Most static contents are the same
- Most dynamic contents are different
- Some dynamic contents can be SHARED across both sites
- Example:

  1. Administrator of site A publishes an entry
  2. The new entry appears only on site A
  3. Administrator of site B is notified of the new entry
  4. Administrator of site B allows entry to appear on site B

At first I thought that would be easy using multisite manager.
Now I’m digging in, I wonder : is that the best way to go ?

Cheers,
L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer needs to be 30 characters long but the simple answer is "yes".

Comment: This is the perfect use case of MSM.